# Customize Sharepoint online List and site page

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a subsite in **Sharepoint Online** office 365 derived from my company's main parent site.
I have embedded one sharepoint list in SitePage, in that I want vistors to add new list items or update the list item but not delete it via. landing site page, what permission should I need to grant for them.
When I grant

- **Contribute permission** : he got access to edit site page also (which is not allowed)
- **Read permission** : site page edit access is restricted but along with it the edit permission for list item is also restricted, he couldn't add/edit the list items.

what and how to define relevant permission to user?

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions from the relevant list settings, if users should only be able to add/edit list items then create a new permission level called `Update Only`, the default permission levels don't have this type of permission out-of-the-box.
Go to `Site Settings -> Permission Settings -> Permission Levels` then click on `Add a permission Level`, here's the official MS documentation on how to accomplish that:

[Create a permission level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels#create-a-permission-level)

Then for the new permission level set only the permissions users need to add/edit items, usually it will be the following:

> 1. Add Items  -  Add items to lists and add documents to document libraries.
> 2. Edit Items  -  Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.
> 3. View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries.
> 4. View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists.

[image]

Then in the list settings users can be granted the `Update Only` permission level.